# calling a LS agent from SSJS

Tags: parameters, xpages, agent, xpages-ssjs

I'm having trouble passing a param from a SSJS action to a LS backend agent. In the SSJS i have this code:

```
var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
doc.appendItemValue("DeleteDocs",arr);
doc.appendItemValue("Form","frmWFSDeleteDocs");
var UNID = doc.getUniversalID();
dBar.info(UNID, "Doc ID");
doc.appendItemValue("ParentID",UNID);
doc.save();
var agent:NotesAgent = database.getAgent("WFSDeleteDocs");
dBar.info(doc.getItemValueString("ParentID"));
agent.runOnServer(doc.getItemValueString("ParentID"))
```

The UNID that is displayed in the dBar info is the correct document UNID.
In my LS agent I have this code:

```
Set agent = s.CurrentAgent    
NoteId = agent.ParameterDocID 
Print "Notes Param " + NoteID
Set thisDoc = db.Getdocumentbyunid(NoteId)
```

In the log the NoteID is not the UNID but 
HTTP Server: Agent printing: Notes Param 5A3439

and of course the getDocumentbyunid fails. My understand looking at the help is that this should be the same value as I insert as the param in the runOnserver.
Am I missing something

Comment: You're supposed to pass a NoteID, not a UNID, but I can't think of why the code you posted would store a NoteID...

Comment: From what i get you are creating a new doc, then retrieving this doc's unid, and only later you save it for the first time, right? I don't have domino designer at hand but as far as i remember the *final* unid is not created before the doc is saved the first time, so that might be one reason why the passed id is not the one you expect. Like tim i can't guess why the ids might be changing. The one that you see from your agent code has the format of a noteId, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run the agent using `agent.run(<note id>)`. This will transfer the note id to the agent and you can then read the note id using `agent.getParameterDocID()`.

So, in your case do this in SSJS:

```
var agent:NotesAgent = database.getAgent("WFSDeleteDocs");
agent.run(doc.getItemValueString("ParentID"))
```

**Update:** If you want to run the agent as signer, use sessionAsSigner:

```
var backendDb:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(session.getServerName(), database.getFilePath());
var agent:NotesAgent = backendDb.getAgent("WFSDeleteDocs");
agent.run(doc.getItemValueString("ParentID"))
```

Comment: But I have to have it runOnServer so that it runs with a different ID. I don't think a simple agent.run will get what I need.

Comment: You can use sessionAsSigner for this. I have updated my answer

Comment: Very Strange, but still don't get the UNID passed via the agent param even though the UNID is correct in the SSJS dBar.info statements. I worked out a different way to make this work. Because the document the SSJS is a temporary container I have a view that contains it and then just get the document from the view. Possible issues if two people invoke the agent at the same time, but that will be highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing NoteID and UniversalID

UniversalIDs are universal across different replicas of databases, often even globally universal like UUIDs or GUIDs

NoteIDs are local to a Notes-database. The same document in different replicas of a database has usually different NoteIDs assigned to the same document.

**Agent parameter passing MUST be a NoteID. There is no other option at all.**

I don't know the SSJS Notes/Domino-API, but you should be able to use something like this:

```
agent.runOnServer(doc.getNoteID())
```

So your SSJS code would be

```
var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
doc.appendItemValue("DeleteDocs",arr);
doc.appendItemValue("Form","frmWFSDeleteDocs");
doc.save();
var agent:NotesAgent = database.getAgent("WFSDeleteDocs");
agent.runOnServer(doc.getNoteID())
```

And your Notes-agent-code should use

```
Set thisDoc = db.GetdocumentbyId(NoteId)
```

instead of

```
Set thisDoc = db.Getdocumentbyunid(NoteId)
```

Your complete Notes-agent

```
Set agent = s.CurrentAgent    
NoteId = agent.ParameterDocID 
Print "Notes Param " + NoteID
Set thisDoc = db.GetdocumentbyId(NoteId)
```